# Specify heigh of images in css doesn't work

Tags: html, css, django

I am currently working on a django blog. However, I am experiencing some difficulties with the size of the post thumbnails. Here's a picture:

[image]

What I marked in yellow is how the image should be filling the space. The width is fine, but the heigh isn't working well as you can see.

Here's the code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<style>
  img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    
  }
</style>

        <!-- Post-->
        {% for obj in object_list %}
        <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch">
          {% if not forloop.first and not forloop.last %}
          <div class="image col-lg-5"><img src="{{ obj.thumbnail.url }}" alt="..."></div> #Here's the image
          {% endif %}
          <div class="text col-lg-7">
            <div class="text-inner d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="content">
                <header class="post-header">
                  <div class="category">
                    {% for cat in obj.categories.all %}
                    <a href="#">{{ cat }}</a>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                  <a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <h2 class="h4">{{ obj.title }}</h2>
                    </a>
                </header>
                <p>{{ obj.overview|linebreaks|truncatechars:200 }}</p>
                <footer class="post-footer d-flex align-items-center"><a href="#" class="author d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                    <div class="avatar"><img src="{{ obj.author.profile_picture.url }}" alt="..." class="img-fluid"></div>
                    <div class="title"><span>{{ obj.author }}</span></div></a>
                  <div class="date"><i class="icon-clock"></i> {{ obj.timestamp|timesince }} ago</div>
                  <div class="comments"><i class="icon-comment"></i>{{ obj.comment_count }}</div>
                </footer>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% if forloop.first or forloop.last %}
          <div class="image col-lg-5"><img src="{{ obj.thumbnail.url }}" alt="..."></div> #Here's the image
          {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is `<img>`'s default behaivor to fill the whole width and height, often losing its aspect ratio.

The fact that it did not happen in your case, most likely is because you set `object-fit: contain` somewhere in your css.

You either remove `object-fit: contain` setting, or you can use

```
  img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: fill !important; # fill is the default value.  
  }
```

Comment: I've tried that and it still doesn't work, I'm trying to figure out where I set the object-fit: contain. But I don't remember setting that

Comment: Why should I do that? I don't understand. Could you enlighten me, please?

Comment: clear browser history is the first thing you will do when your newly applied css is not working. browswer caches your css.

Comment: Ok. Maybe it’s a stupid question. Should I delete all data?

Comment: ```cached images and files``` is the must -delete one. but googl'e default setting should just work.

Comment: Ok. I've tried that and it's still the same thing

Comment: can you try ```width: 100% !important``` and ```height: 100% !important```?

Comment: Still doesn't work. I certainly have no idea why this is happening

Comment: yeah. I think css is affected by many things around the element. One possible way  to debug is to get the minimum code / minimum css to reproduce this in program like jsfiddle. By doing it, you might find that the problem is not reside in this small element per se, but in some other places.